# Failed to resolve: com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.5

Tags: android-studio

I have added this dependency in my app from github. I tried changing the version but it keeps giving the error "Failed to resolve: com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.5".

```
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.5'
```

This is the error in the build.

```
Failed to resolve: com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.5
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same problem.
You need to update X Y and Z with the latest version. In my case it was 2.6.0.
You can find the latest version [here](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)